# Compund method of specifying width of an input type = "image"

Tags: html, css

Is there a way I can assign a width to a element like 60%+12px in css. Although it sounds awkward but I need this to be absolutely sure of multiple browser handling issues.

I understand there's a way of doing it using javascript by dynamically finding the width of the container and solving the expression. But I wanted to do that in css without manipulating the dom using js.

The solution should be browser independent for obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the width 60%, then add the 12px as margin (6px on each side).

Comment: well in my scenario I require the inner width to be 60%+12, anyways that layout changed all together so the problem got digged down.